# Realm Migration with Unnormalized data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Let's say you have a realm object like

```
class Person: Object {
    var dynamic firstName: String = ""
    var dynamic lastName: String = ""
}
```

Now, I want to upgrade the database and extract out the lastName into a new class like this

```
class LastName: Object {
    var dynamic sirName: String = ""

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "sirName"
    }
}

class Person: Object {
    var dynamic firstName: String = ""
    var dynamic lastName: LastName!
}
```

What would the migration look like?  I have tried a simple migration, but this can cause multiple LastName objects with the same primaryKey.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1, //This must be larger than the previous schemaVersion
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerate(Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                let lastName = oldObject!["lastName"] as! String
                let newValue: [String: String] = ["sirName": lastName]
                let createdObject = migration.create(LastName.className(), value: newValue)
                newObject!["lastName"] = createdObject
            }
        }
})

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = configuration // Set the new configuration as default

let realm = try! Realm() // Open the default realm to perform the migration
```

To add, this now works with a `primaryKey` as well, with models looking like this:

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: LastName!
}

class LastName: Object {
    dynamic var sirName: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "sirName"
    }
}
```

But this migration won't work if there are duplicates of `lastName` due to the `primaryKey` being a unique identifier for each object, so either you should make sure that there will never be duplicates, use another property for the `primaryKey` or not use a `primaryKey` at all in the `LastName` object.

Comment: This is not working. it is trying to set a dictionary to the newObject!["lastName"] property

Comment: @NoName Sorry, fixed it and it works as it should now!

Comment: I believe this will still possibly give duplicate Lastname objects with the same primaryKey, thus giving an error

Comment: Yes, you're right. But **only if there are duplicate values** for the surnames, and I'm not really sure why you'd limit the object to only be able to have one value for each unique object, especially if we're actually talking about surnames. If you know that you won't have duplicates then this method will work.

Comment: @NoName See my expanded answer, it should clear up any questions you have regarding this.